# How to get notified about changed if_index

Tags: macos, kernel, netfilter, network-interface, sysfs

**What we are doing:**
We are using netfilter library.
Our module(say "X-engine") reads and caches the if_index.

**The real issue:**
If the kernel decides to change the if_index for some reason, X-engine cached if_index does not gets updated and it starts dropping the packet because their is mismatch between if_index what is cached in module-X and what is actually present in kernel.

**What we are looking for:**
Now is there a way/API by which module-X can be notified about this change event so that module-X updates it's cached if_index appropriately?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to use rtnetlink socket for monitoring and processing RTM_NEWLINK and RTM_DELLINK messages (what provides a information about creating or removing a specific network interface). More info at http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/rtnetlink.7.html

Comment: How do we simulate this scenario without hardcoding the if_index. Is there a way by which I can change the if_index associated to an existing interface?